# Does every vector space have an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I have a question: *Does every vector space have an inner product?*

I think, yes. But I failed to find an essential reason. If it does not exist, then give me a counterexample. Thanks.

Comment: If a space is an inner product space it satisfies Parallelogram law. Can you find an example of a normed vector space where this law doesn't hold? Hint: $L^p$.

Comment: I saw this post. But I don't understand... So, I want an easier example than that. I cannot have tried because this question is so abstract... we finally assume that the given vector space has the finite dimension.

Answer (score 3):

Take a vector space $X$ over $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$) and fix a basis $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$.

If $x,y\in X$, then they can be uniquely expressed as
$$
x=\sum_{i\in I}c_iv_i,\quad y=\sum_{i\in I}d_iv_i,
$$
with each of the sum above finite.

Define
$$\langle u,v\rangle=\sum_{i\in I}c_id_i.
$$
This is an inner product in $X$.

In the case of $\mathbb C$, the definition is
$$\langle u,v\rangle=\sum_{i\in I}c_i\overline{d_i}.
$$

Comment: I edited the first inline, please see that this is what you meant

Comment: Yeah, I see. Should I define the inner product over real or complex? If not, is it possible that an inner product does not exist?

Comment: Inner product is always definable. You should choose real or complex depending on the field over which your vector space is defined on.

Answer (score 0):

Inner products are defined for spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$ only.

The reason is that in the definition we require $$\langle u,v \rangle=\overline{\langle v,u\rangle}$$

and what is the meaning of $$\overline{\langle v,u\rangle}$$

when $\langle v,u \rangle$ is not complex ?

Comment: If the given scalar is neither real nor complex, then some inner product may exists in the different way? If only the scalar is complex(real), the above definition, I think, is working.