# Visualize and define a vector space without dot / inner product

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples, inner-products

I'm trying to rebase my know how in linear algebra, restart from scratch to get a more formal and useful set of definitions to help me with computer programming stuff .

One of the first concepts is a *vector space*, which is a space with :

- a field $F$ of scalars
- a group of vectors $V$
- a vector sum and a vector multiplication

  - said operations are commutative and associative
  - the sum has $0$ as identity
  - the multiplication has $1$ as identity

A *vector space* is also an *algebraic structure* .

You then use *vector spaces* to define *Hilbert spaces* .

An *Hilbert space* is a *vector space* where  you can perform an *inner product*, in particular a *scalar product* is needed ( aka *dot product* ) .

I'm puzzled by the introduction of this *scalar product* and why is needed, the reported consequences of this are that :

- you can talk about:

  - angles
  - distances
  - orthogonality of lines
- limits exist, and this is good so you can apply calculus to Hilbert spaces
- and because limits exist ( I guess that this means that everything always converge to a point ) you can pretty much always express an Hilbert space ( or elements of an *Hilbert space* (?) ) with a series, a series of elements from your field ( numbers ) or a series of functions

It's not explicitly stated in any resource I found but I think that *Hilbert spaces* are not *algebraic structure* as *vector spaces* are, you lose this property .

Assuming that I haven't made any mistakes, is this a list of consequences from just having a *scalar product* defined for a *vector space* ?

What is a *vector space* without a *scalar product* defined ? What's a *vector space* that is not an *Hilbert space* ? How it looks like ?

I'm really having some troubles in visualizing this with some geometries or just some graphs .

Comment: Posts related to part about inner product spaces: [Is there a vector space that cannot be an inner product space?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247425/is-there-a-vector-space-that-cannot-be-an-inner-product-space) and [Does every vector space have an inner product?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976740/does-every-vector-space-have-an-inner-product).

Comment: About Hilbert spaces: [Can all real/complex vector spaces be equipped with a Hilbert space structure?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427834/can-all-real-complex-vector-spaces-be-equipped-with-a-hilbert-space-structure) 
(Which is related to [Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space. Prove that every Hamel basis of $X$ is uncountable.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217516/let-x-be-an-infinite-dimensional-banach-space-prove-that-every-hamel-basis-of)
and [Cardinality of a Hamel basis](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141535/cardinality-of-a-hamel-basis)).

Answer (score 1):

Each Hilbert space $(X, <\cdot,\cdot>)$ is also a normed space $(X, ||\cdot||)$ with norm  $||x|| := \sqrt {<x,x>}, x\in X$.

Concerning the opposite direction: If $(X, ||\cdot||)$ is a normed vector space, then its norm must satisfy the parallelogram law $||x+y||^2 + ||x-y||^2=2||x||^2 + 2||y||^2$ in order to derive from an inner product.

Not every normed space is also a Hilbert space. The p-norm on $X=\mathbb R^n, n>1$, defined as $||x||_p:=(\sum_{i=1,...,n} |x_i|^p)^\frac{1}{p}, p\neq 2,$ does not derive from an inner product.